# How to handle errors with lowest complexity and only one return

Tags: php, function, return

I want to avoid using multiples return in my functions, but I can't see how to interrupt them without adding a lot of `else` in a case like this :

```
public function foo($number)
{
    if ($number > 8)
    {
        return ' > 8';
    }

    if (exist($number))
    {
        return $number . ' exist';
    }

    return $this->bar($number);
}
```

My use case is to display an error message for some invalid cases and don't execute what's left in the function.

Comment: What does your last return do, is that an additional validation check? As it looks like you are returning error messages, I would store them all in an error array and return that.

Comment: @jeroen no, it could be a database manipulation.

Comment: The it looks like `foo()` is doing a bit too much; returning error messages *or* the result of a separate database operation does not sound very logical and would be hard to process by whatever calls that method.

Comment: @jeroen what you've pointed out seems right. In this case foo() can return multiples kind of datas (errors or whatever return `bar()`).
I should split that function. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public function foo($number)
{
    if ($number > 8) {
        $return_value = ' > 8';
    } elseif (exist($number)) {
        $return_value = $number . ' exist';
    }

    return $return_value ?? $this->bar($number);
}
```

But AFAIK, multiple return are OK, since functions are readable enough. One of my main concern is to have small function, just a few lines, so I don't have to scroll, and I can understand it in seconds. So even if there are three `return` cases it's still readable.

Comment: But my main concern is to don't trigger $this->bar($number) is one of the condition is met.

Comment: Yes, I read it in one of your comments so I fixed it 11 minutes ago. `$this->bar($number)` is only called if no other condition is met.